# Java: Lectura de números complejos desde un txt

Tags: java

tengo un problema he intentado leer números complejos desde un txt en java
la información del txt es la siguiente:

2 //Numero de columnas

2 //Numero de filas

1.0+2.0i, 3.0+4.0i

1.0+2.0i, 3.0+4.0i

He implementado la siguiente función para tratar de leer el numero complejo, donde en consola me da el siguiente error:

> incompatible types: String cannot be converted to COMPLEJO

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
class COMPLEJO
{
    //Declaracion de atributos
    private float real;
    private float imaginario;

    //Definicion de los metodos:

    //Metodo constructor
    COMPLEJO() //Constructor por default.
    {
        real = 0;
        imaginario = 0;

        System.out.println("Se ha ejecutado el contrsuctor por defecto");
    }

    //Constructor con parametros.
    COMPLEJO(float r, float i)
    {
        real = r;
        imaginario = i;
    }

    COMPLEJO(float r)
    {
        real = r;
        imaginario = 0;
    }
}

class MATRIZCOMPLEJA
{
    private COMPLEJO [][]Mx; //Variable de referencia.
    private int M;  //Filas
    private int N; //Columnas

    public void LeerMatrizCompleja() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        String archivo = "pruebaMatrices.txt";
        Scanner Lectura; 
        Lectura = new Scanner(new File(archivo));
        int M, N, i, j;

        MATRIZCOMPLEJA MatrizA[][];
        MATRIZCOMPLEJA MatrizB[][];

        System.out.println("Numero de filas: ");
        M = Lectura.nextInt();
        System.out.println(M);
        System.out.println("Numero de columnas: ");
        N = Lectura.nextInt();
        System.out.println(N);
        
        MatrizA = new MATRIZCOMPLEJA[M][N];
        
        for(i=0; i<M; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            {
                Mx[i][j] = Lectura.nextLine();
                System.out.println(MatrizA[i][j] + " \t");
            }
        }

        MatrizB = new MATRIZCOMPLEJA[M][N];
        
        for(i=0; i<M; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            {
                Mx[i][j] = Lectura.nextLine();
                System.out.println(MatrizB[i][j] + " \t");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ya he intentado usar next, hasNext, nextLine usando patrones pero consigo el mismo error.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, procura poner la traza completa del error que te sale, no solo el resumen del error. Así sera más fáci poder ayudarte. :) Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta todas las veces que necesites, usando el enlace Editar que está justo bajo la pregunta

Comment: Es imposible ayudarte si A) No nos dices exactamente cual es el error y B) Utilizas métodos de los cuales no podemos ver la implementación... Somos programadores, no adivinos!

Comment: Es necesario que publiques la clase COMPLEJO o su constructor para ver como crear dichos objetos. Se puede tomar el String leído del archivo y crear un objeto COMPLEJO a partir del mismo. Por ultimo, respeta la convención para nombres de [java](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenci%C3%B3n_de_nombres_(programaci%C3%B3n)#Java) así es más fácil entender tu código.

Answer (score 0):

El detalle, como dice el mensaje del compilador es que lo que lee tu Scanner es tipo String (u otro valor primitivo) y no puedes convertirlo directamente en un objeto de tu clase Complejo. Para ese fin, tendrías que programar un constructor que reciba el String y lo convierta en Complejo. Por otro lado, leer matrices bidimensionales del archivo tiene más complejidad de lo que presentas en tu ejemplo...
Primer punto: Convertir String a complejo. En este sentido, y tomando en cuenta que tanto el valor real como el imaginario de un complejo pueden ser positivos o negativos, te recomendaría que el string sea algo como "N,N" (por ejemplo "3,4", "1,-2", etc)... De tal manera, el constructor sería algo como:

```
public Complejo(String cadena) throws Exception {
    String[] tmp;
    tmp = cadena.split(",");
    this.real = Float.parseFloat(tmp[0]);
    this.imaginario = Float.parseFloat(tmp[1];)
}
```

Después, retomando la lectura de tu archivo, todos los números complejos irían en línea, es decir:
1,3
-2,5
1,-1
etc...
Finalmente, dentro de tu código lo que debes hacer es ingresar los números complejos que vayas leyendo del archivo a la matriz con:

```
Mx[i][j] = new Complejo ( Lectura.nextLine() );
```

Finalmente... Te recomiendo que uses las convenciones de nombrado para que tu código sea más claro... NOMBRE_DE_CONSTANTE, NombreDeClase, nombreDeMetodoAtributoOVariable (Complejo porque es clase, lectura porque es variable, etc).